# RasPi3B+ won't read SD cards

Tags: pi-3, boot, hardware, sd-card, boot-issues

As stated the old rpi 3B+ worked fine until 1 boot where it no longer read the SD cards. (ACT light not lighting up at all, PWR light constantly on.)
Happened after I tried swapping from dynamic IP to static on my local network as the program I want to run on it requires local network and dynamic is used for programming/testing. Didn't fault the first time I swapped but the second.

Had the exact same setup with a different rpi 3B+, same SD, same power source, and it booted fine. (Although still haven't tried swapping ip setup)

I'm also using PiPlates so I'm not sure if that's causing an issue.

Comment: it's unlikely any change you did has stopped the Pi from even attempting to boot (zero green light activity means it's not even trying) - perhaps you fried the pi with those Pi plates - connect it to a monitor, do you get any output at all? Try booting from a USB thumb drive, 3B+ does that out of the box